# Serial.println changes return value of function (Arduino)

Tags: c++, function, arduino

I've been experiencing some very odd behaviour from what should be a very simple function: an integer is passed to the function, and depending on its value will return an unsigned char specific to that integer.

I kept experiencing a problem in which it would return a different value to those that are hard coded into the function. I've had to rewrite the code a number of times to get it to stop happening, but I have found a way to recreate it every time to illustrate how something that shouldn't change the return value is doing.

Below is an example sketch to illustrate:

```
unsigned char* brokenFunction(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            //Serial.println("Break it...");
            unsigned char retval[8] = {
                0b01110,
                0b11011,
                0b10001,
                0b10001,
                0b10001,
                0b10001,
                0b10001,
                0b11111
            };

            return retval;
        }
        break;

        case 5:
        {
            unsigned char retval[8] = {
                0b01110,
                0b11011,
                0b11111,
                0b11111,
                0b11111,
                0b11111,
                0b11111,
                0b11111
            };

            return retval;
        }
        break;
    }
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    unsigned char* array = brokenFunction(0);
    Serial.println(*array);
}

void loop()
{

}
```

On line 7 is a call to `Serial.println` which is currently commented out. If you run the sketch on your Arduino with this line commented out, the `Serial.println` call in the `setup` function will return the value `14` (which is correct).

If, however, you uncomment line 7, the `Serial.println` call in the `setup` function will now return what seems like a random value; for my last test it was the value `91`; see the serial window log below:

`14
    Break it...
    91`

As you can see, my first attempt returned 14, but the subsequent attempt with the extra `Serial.println` call resulted in the return value being changed.

Does anyone have any idea what may be going wrong here? There were other things I did that managed to replicate this too, but this is the most simple one to use as an example. It's almost as if, if the function is taking a bit longer to finish that the return value is being corrupted some how.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a local array from the function `brokenFunction(int id)`, which stops existing when you return, causing undefined behavior from that point on.

Comment: How would you recommend I return the values if constructing them inside the function first is not possible? I am going to have quite a number of these values that could possibly be returned, which is why I was going to have a function to return the appropriate one so that they aren't all being stored in memory at once. For example, I may have 30 possible return values but only one that needs to be stored in memory depending on the context it is being used in.

Comment: @rastating Pass an array to the function with the array size information.